# Why my robot is lying down in gazebo simulator?

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, gazebo

this is my first post about ROS and Gazebo also I am new in ROS.
I spawn KUKA robot in Gazebo using urdf file from KUKA github repository
following answer from this question I spawned my urdf file in gazebo simulator and KUKA robot appeared in simulator but problem is that is lying down like is attached on floor for some reason. 
Here is picture in Gazebo:
[image: gazebo simulation]

This is my launch file:

```
<launch>
<!-- We resume the logic in empty_world.launch, changing only the name of the world to be launched -->
<include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
  <arg name="paused" value="false"/>
  <arg name="use_sim_time" value="true"/>
  <arg name="gui" value="true"/>
  <arg name="headless" value="false"/>
  <arg name="debug" value="false"/>
</include>
<node name="spawn_urdf" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="-file $(find kuka_kr210_support)/urdf/kr210l150.urdf -urdf -z 1 -model baxter" />
</launch>
```

EDIT:
I fixed base link for the world, added transmission, controllers for each axis and gazebo plugin. now my urdf file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!-- =================================================================================== -->
<!-- |    This document was autogenerated by xacro from kr16_2.xacro                   | -->
<!-- |    EDITING THIS FILE BY HAND IS NOT RECOMMENDED                                 | -->
<!-- =================================================================================== -->
<!--Generates a urdf from the macro in kr16_2_macro.xacro -->
<robot name="kuka_kr16_2" xmlns:xacro="http://wiki.ros.org/xacro">
  <!-- LINKS -->


  <!-- base link -->
  <link name="base_link">
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <mass value="2"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.01" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.01" iyz="0" izz="0.01"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://kuka_kr16_support/meshes/kr16_2/visual/base_link.dae"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://kuka_kr16_support/meshes/kr16_2/collision/base_link.stl"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <!-- link 1 (A1) -->
  <link name="link_1">
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <mass value="2"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.01" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.01" iyz="0" izz="0.01"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://kuka_kr16_support/meshes/kr16_2/visual/link_1.dae"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://kuka_kr16_support/meshes/kr16_2/collision/link_1.stl"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <!-- link 2 -->
  <link name="link_2">
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <mass value="2"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.01" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.01" iyz="0" izz="0.01"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://kuka_kr16_support/meshes/kr16_2/visual/link_2.dae"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://kuka_kr16_support/meshes/kr16_2/collision/link_2.stl"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <!-- link 3 -->
  <link name="link_3">
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <mass value="2"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.01" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.01" iyz="0" izz="0.01"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://kuka_kr16_support/meshes/kr16_2/visual/link_3.dae"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://kuka_kr16_support/meshes/kr16_2/collision/link_3.stl"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <!-- link 4 -->
  <link name="link_4">
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <mass value="2"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.01" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.01" iyz="0" izz="0.01"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://kuka_kr16_support/meshes/kr16_2/visual/link_4.dae"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://kuka_kr16_support/meshes/kr16_2/collision/link_4.stl"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <!-- link 5 -->
  <link name="link_5">
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <mass value="2"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.01" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.01" iyz="0" izz="0.01"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://kuka_kr16_support/meshes/kr16_2/visual/link_5.dae"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://kuka_kr16_support/meshes/kr16_2/collision/link_5.stl"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <!-- link 6 -->
  <link name="link_6">
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <mass value="2"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.01" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.01" iyz="0" izz="0.01"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://kuka_kr16_support/meshes/kr16_2/visual/link_6.dae"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://kuka_kr16_support/meshes/kr16_2/collision/link_6.stl"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <!-- tool 0 -->
  <!-- This frame corresponds to the $FLANGE coordinate system in KUKA KRC controllers. 
  <link name="tool0"/> -->

  <!-- END LINKS -->
  <!-- JOINTS -->
  <!-- joint 1 (A1) -->
  <joint name="joint_a1" type="revolute">
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.675"/>
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="link_1"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 -1"/>
    <limit effort="0" lower="-3.22885911619" upper="3.22885911619" velocity="2.72271363311"/>
  </joint>


   <transmission name="trans_joint_a1">
      <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
      <joint name="joint_a1">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
      </joint>
      <actuator name="motor_joint_a1">
        <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
      </actuator>
   </transmission>


  <!-- joint 2 (A2) -->
  <joint name="joint_a2" type="revolute">
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.26 0 0"/>
    <parent link="link_1"/>
    <child link="link_2"/>
    <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
    <limit effort="0" lower="-2.70526034059" upper="0.610865238198" velocity="2.72271363311"/>
  </joint>

   <transmission name="trans_joint_a2">
      <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
      <joint name="joint_a2">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
      </joint>
      <actuator name="motor_joint_a2">
        <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
      </actuator>
   </transmission>

  <!-- joint 3 (A3) -->
  <joint name="joint_a3" type="revolute">
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.68 0 0"/>
    <parent link="link_2"/>
    <child link="link_3"/>
    <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
    <limit effort="0" lower="-2.26892802759" upper="2.68780704807" velocity="2.72271363311"/>
  </joint>

   <transmission name="trans_joint_a3">
      <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
      <joint name="joint_a3">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
      </joint>
      <actuator name="motor_joint_a3">
        <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
      </actuator>
   </transmission>

  <!-- joint 4 (A4) -->
  <joint name="joint_a4" type="revolute">
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.67 0 -0.035"/>
    <parent link="link_3"/>
    <child link="link_4"/>
    <axis xyz="-1 0 0"/>
    <limit effort="0" lower="-6.10865238198" upper="6.10865238198" velocity="5.75958653158"/>
  </joint>

   <transmission name="trans_joint_a4">
      <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
      <joint name="joint_a4">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
      </joint>
      <actuator name="motor_joint_a4">
        <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
      </actuator>
   </transmission>

  <!-- joint 5 (A5) -->
  <joint name="joint_a5" type="revolute">
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <parent link="link_4"/>
    <child link="link_5"/>
    <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
    <limit effort="0" lower="-2.26892802759" upper="2.26892802759" velocity="5.75958653158"/>
  </joint>

   <transmission name="trans_joint_a5">
      <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
      <joint name="joint_a5">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
      </joint>
      <actuator name="motor_joint_a5">
        <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
      </actuator>
   </transmission>

  <!-- joint 6 (A6) -->
  <joint name="joint_a6" type="revolute">
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <parent link="link_5"/>
    <child link="link_6"/>
    <axis xyz="-1 0 0"/>
    <limit effort="0" lower="-6.10865238198" upper="6.10865238198" velocity="10.7337748998"/>
  </joint>

   <transmission name="trans_joint_a6">
      <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
      <joint name="joint_a6">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
      </joint>
      <actuator name="motor_joint_a6">
        <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
      </actuator>
   </transmission>

  <!-- tool frame - fixed frame 
  <joint name="joint_a6-tool0" type="fixed">
    <parent link="link_6"/>
    <child link="tool0"/>
    <origin rpy="0 1.57079632679 0" xyz="0.158 0 0"/>
  </joint>

   <transmission name="trans_joint_a6-tool0">
      <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
      <joint name="joint_a6-tool0">
        <hardwareInterface>EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
      </joint>
      <actuator name="motor_joint_a6-tool0">
        <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
        <hardwareInterface>EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
      </actuator>
   </transmission> -->

  <!-- END JOINTS -->
  <!-- ROS base_link to KUKA $ROBROOT coordinate system transform -->
  <link name="base"/>
  <joint name="base_link-base" type="fixed">
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="base"/>
  </joint>

  <!-- Gazebo world joint -->
  <!-- Used for fixing robot to Gazebo 'base_link' -->
  <link name="world"/>

  <joint name="fixed" type="fixed">
    <parent link="world"/>
    <child link="base_link"/>
  </joint>

<gazebo>
  <plugin name="gazebo_ros_control" filename="libgazebo_ros_control.so">
    <robotNamespace>/kr16_2_gazebo</robotNamespace>
  </plugin>
</gazebo>

</robot>
```

This is controller yaml:

```
# Publish all joint states -----------------------------------
joint_state_controller:
  type: joint_state_controller/JointStateController
  publish_rate: 50

# Position Controllers ---------------------------------------
joint1_position_controller:
  type: effort_controllers/JointPositionController
  #joint: base_link__link_01
  joint: joint_a1
  pid: {p: 100, i: 100, d: 500.0}
joint2_position_controller:
  type: effort_controllers/JointPositionController
  #joint: link_01__link_02
  joint: joint_a2
  pid: {p: 100.0, i: 100, d: 2000.0}
joint3_position_controller:
  type: effort_controllers/JointPositionController
  #joint: link_02__link_03
  joint: joint_a3
  pid: {p: 100.0, i: 50, d: 1000.0}
joint4_position_controller:
  type: effort_controllers/JointPositionController
  #joint: link_03__link_04
  joint: joint_a4
  pid: {p: 100.0, i: 50, d: 200.0}
joint5_position_controller:
  type: effort_controllers/JointPositionController
  #joint: link_04__link_05
  joint: joint_a5
  pid: {p: 100.0, i: 50, d: 70.0}
joint6_position_controller:
  type: effort_controllers/JointPositionController
  #joint: link_05__link_06
  joint: joint_a6
  pid: {p: 100.0, i: 50, d: 70.0}
tool0_position_controller:
  type: effort_controllers/JointPositionController
  joint: link_06__tool0
  #joint: joint1
  pid: {p: 100.0, i: 50, d: 70.0}
```

and this is my launch file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>


  <arg name="paused" default="false"/>
  <arg name="gazebo_gui" default="true"/>
  <arg name="urdf_path" default="$(find kuka_kr16_support)/urdf/kr16_2_gazebo.urdf"/>

  <!-- startup simulated world -->
  <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="world_name" default="worlds/empty.world"/>
    <arg name="paused" value="$(arg paused)"/>
    <arg name="gui" value="$(arg gazebo_gui)"/>
  </include>

  <!-- send robot urdf to param server -->
  <param name="robot_description" textfile="$(arg urdf_path)" />

  <!-- Load controllers -->
  <rosparam ns="/kr16_2_gazebo" command="load" file="$(find kuka_kr16_moveit_gazebo)/config/joints.yaml" />

  <!-- push robot_description to factory and spawn robot in gazebo at the origin, change x,y,z arguments to spawn in a different position -->
  <node name="spawn_gazebo_model" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="-urdf -param robot_description -model robot -x 0 -y 0 -z 0"
    respawn="false" output="screen" />

  <!-- Controllers -->
  <node name="controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner"
    respawn="false" output="screen" ns="/kr16_2_gazebo"
    args="--namespace=/kr16_2_gazebo
    joint_state_controller
    joint1_position_controller
    joint2_position_controller
    joint3_position_controller
    joint4_position_controller
    joint5_position_controller
    joint6_position_controller
    --timeout 60">
  </node>


</launch>
```

And when I launch it in terminal this is output:

> WARNING: Package name "KUKA_KR16_moveit_Luka1" does not follow the
>   naming conventions. It should start with a lower case letter and only
>   contain lower case letters, digits, underscores, and dashes. ...
>   logging to
>   /home/gazebo/.ros/log/133adcf4-5e8d-11e9-8069-000c2911adc8/roslaunch-ubuntu-3085.log
>   Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile. Press
>   Ctrl-C to interrupt Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.
>
> WARNING: Package name "KUKA_KR16_moveit_Luka1" does not follow the
>   naming conventions. It should start with a lower case letter and only
>   contain lower case letters, digits, underscores, and dashes. started
>   roslaunch server http://ubuntu:35047/
>
> ## SUMMARY
>
> PARAMETERS  * /gazebo/enable_ros_network: True  *
>   /kr16_2_gazebo/joint1_position_controller/joint: joint_a1  *
>   /kr16_2_gazebo/joint1_position_controller/pid/d: 500.0  *
>   /kr16_2_gazebo/joint1_position_controller/pid/i: 100  *
>   /kr16_2_gazebo/joint1_position_controller/pid/p: 100  *
>   /kr16_2_gazebo/joint1_position_controller/type: effort_controller... 
>   * /kr16_2_gazebo/joint2_position_controller/joint: joint_a2  * /kr16_2_gazebo/joint2_position_controller/pid/d: 2000.0  *
>   /kr16_2_gazebo/joint2_position_controller/pid/i: 100  *
>   /kr16_2_gazebo/joint2_position_controller/pid/p: 100.0  *
>   /kr16_2_gazebo/joint2_position_controller/type: effort_controller... 
>   * /kr16_2_gazebo/joint3_position_controller/joint: joint_a3  * /kr16_2_gazebo/joint3_position_controller/pid/d: 1000.0  *
>   /kr16_2_gazebo/joint3_position_controller/pid/i: 50  *
>   /kr16_2_gazebo/joint3_position_controller/pid/p: 100.0  *
>   /kr16_2_gazebo/joint3_position_controller/type: effort_controller... 
>   * /kr16_2_gazebo/joint4_position_controller/joint: joint_a4  * /kr16_2_gazebo/joint4_position_controller/pid/d: 200.0  *
>   /kr16_2_gazebo/joint4_position_controller/pid/i: 50  *
>   /kr16_2_gazebo/joint4_position_controller/pid/p: 100.0  *
>   /kr16_2_gazebo/joint4_position_controller/type: effort_controller... 
>   * /kr16_2_gazebo/joint5_position_controller/joint: joint_a5  * /kr16_2_gazebo/joint5_position_controller/pid/d: 70.0  *
>   /kr16_2_gazebo/joint5_position_controller/pid/i: 50  *
>   /kr16_2_gazebo/joint5_position_controller/pid/p: 100.0  *
>   /kr16_2_gazebo/joint5_position_controller/type: effort_controller... 
>   * /kr16_2_gazebo/joint6_position_controller/joint: joint_a6  * /kr16_2_gazebo/joint6_position_controller/pid/d: 70.0  *
>   /kr16_2_gazebo/joint6_position_controller/pid/i: 50  *
>   /kr16_2_gazebo/joint6_position_controller/pid/p: 100.0  *
>   /kr16_2_gazebo/joint6_position_controller/type: effort_controller... 
>   * /kr16_2_gazebo/joint_state_controller/publish_rate: 50  * /kr16_2_gazebo/joint_state_controller/type: joint_state_contr...  *
>   /kr16_2_gazebo/tool0_position_controller/joint: link_06__tool0  *
>   /kr16_2_gazebo/tool0_position_controller/pid/d: 70.0  *
>   /kr16_2_gazebo/tool0_position_controller/pid/i: 50  *
>   /kr16_2_gazebo/tool0_position_controller/pid/p: 100.0  *
>   /kr16_2_gazebo/tool0_position_controller/type: effort_controller...  *
>   /robot_description:
>
> NODES   /kr16_2_gazebo/
>       controller_spawner (controller_manager/spawner)   /
>       gazebo (gazebo_ros/gzserver)
>       gazebo_gui (gazebo_ros/gzclient)
>       spawn_gazebo_model (gazebo_ros/spawn_model)
>
> auto-starting new master process[master]: started with pid [3096]
>   ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
>
> setting /run_id to 133adcf4-5e8d-11e9-8069-000c2911adc8 WARNING:
>   Package name "KUKA_KR16_moveit_Luka1" does not follow the naming
>   conventions. It should start with a lower case letter and only contain
>   lower case letters, digits, underscores, and dashes.
>   process[rosout-1]: started with pid [3107] started core service
>   [/rosout] process[gazebo-2]: started with pid [3110]
>   process[gazebo_gui-3]: started with pid [3119]
>   process[spawn_gazebo_model-4]: started with pid [3124]
>   process[kr16_2_gazebo/controller_spawner-5]: started with pid [3125]
>   WARNING: Package name "KUKA_KR16_moveit_Luka1" does not follow the
>   naming conventions. It should start with a lower case letter and only
>   contain lower case letters, digits, underscores, and dashes. WARNING:
>   Package name "KUKA_KR16_moveit_Luka1" does not follow the naming
>   conventions. It should start with a lower case letter and only contain
>   lower case letters, digits, underscores, and dashes. WARNING: Package
>   name "KUKA_KR16_moveit_Luka1" does not follow the naming conventions.
>   It should start with a lower case letter and only contain lower case
>   letters, digits, underscores, and dashes. WARNING: Package name
>   "KUKA_KR16_moveit_Luka1" does not follow the naming conventions. It
>   should start with a lower case letter and only contain lower case
>   letters, digits, underscores, and dashes. [INFO] [1555229566.121403,
>   0.000000]: Controller Spawner: Waiting for service /kr16_2_gazebo/controller_manager/load_controller [ INFO]
>   [1555229567.920658309]: Finished loading Gazebo ROS API Plugin. [
>   INFO] [1555229567.922362082]: waitForService: Service
>   [/gazebo_gui/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised,
>   waiting... [ INFO] [1555229567.927517546]: Finished loading Gazebo ROS
>   API Plugin. [ INFO] [1555229567.928969037]: waitForService: Service
>   [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
>   [INFO] [1555229569.090114, 0.000000]: Loading model XML from ros
>   parameter robot_description [INFO] [1555229569.100970, 0.000000]:
>   Waiting for service /gazebo/spawn_urdf_model [INFO]
>   [1555229569.708130, 0.000000]: Calling service
>   /gazebo/spawn_urdf_model [ INFO] [1555229569.740163120, 0.023000000]:
>   waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] is now
>   available. [INFO] [1555229570.489737, 0.159000]: Spawn status:
>   SpawnModel: Successfully spawned entity [ INFO] [1555229570.502446729,
>   0.159000000]: Physics dynamic reconfigure ready. [ INFO] [1555229570.679725950, 0.159000000]: Loading gazebo_ros_control plugin
>   [ INFO] [1555229570.680028318, 0.159000000]: Starting
>   gazebo_ros_control plugin in namespace: /kr16_2_gazebo [ INFO]
>   [1555229570.680620454, 0.159000000]: gazebo_ros_control plugin is
>   waiting for model URDF in parameter [/robot_description] on the ROS
>   param server. [spawn_gazebo_model-4] process has finished cleanly log
>   file:
>   /home/gazebo/.ros/log/133adcf4-5e8d-11e9-8069-000c2911adc8/spawn_gazebo_model-4*.log
>   [ INFO] [1555229570.868346785, 0.159000000]: Loaded
>   gazebo_ros_control. [INFO] [1555229570.971088, 0.255000]: Controller
>   Spawner: Waiting for service
>   /kr16_2_gazebo/controller_manager/switch_controller [INFO]
>   [1555229570.980829, 0.257000]: Controller Spawner: Waiting for service
>   /kr16_2_gazebo/controller_manager/unload_controller [INFO]
>   [1555229570.987506, 0.263000]: Loading controller:
>   joint_state_controller [INFO] [1555229571.017423, 0.294000]: Loading
>   controller: joint1_position_controller [INFO] [1555229571.106571,
>   0.377000]: Loading controller: joint2_position_controller [INFO] [1555229571.162822, 0.424000]: Loading controller:
>   joint3_position_controller [INFO] [1555229571.229486, 0.475000]:
>   Loading controller: joint4_position_controller [INFO]
>   [1555229571.288503, 0.515000]: Loading controller:
>   joint5_position_controller [INFO] [1555229571.361675, 0.563000]:
>   Loading controller: joint6_position_controller [INFO]
>   [1555229571.418728, 0.607000]: Controller Spawner: Loaded controllers:
>   joint_state_controller, joint1_position_controller,
>   joint2_position_controller, joint3_position_controller,
>   joint4_position_controller, joint5_position_controller,
>   joint6_position_controller [INFO] [1555229571.426332, 0.612000]:
>   Started controllers: joint_state_controller,
>   joint1_position_controller, joint2_position_controller,
>   joint3_position_controller, joint4_position_controller,
>   joint5_position_controller, joint6_position_controller

From output I can see that all controllers are loaded,to confirm it here is output of rostopic:

> ```
> /clock
> /gazebo/link_states
> /gazebo/model_states
> /gazebo/parameter_descriptions
> /gazebo/parameter_updates
> /gazebo/set_link_state
> /gazebo/set_model_state
> /kr16_2_gazebo/joint1_position_controller/command
> /kr16_2_gazebo/joint1_position_controller/pid/parameter_descriptions
> /kr16_2_gazebo/joint1_position_controller/pid/parameter_updates
> /kr16_2_gazebo/joint1_position_controller/state
> /kr16_2_gazebo/joint2_position_controller/command
> /kr16_2_gazebo/joint2_position_controller/pid/parameter_descriptions
> /kr16_2_gazebo/joint2_position_controller/pid/parameter_updates
> /kr16_2_gazebo/joint2_position_controller/state
> /kr16_2_gazebo/joint3_position_controller/command
> /kr16_2_gazebo/joint3_position_controller/pid/parameter_descriptions
> /kr16_2_gazebo/joint3_position_controller/pid/parameter_updates
> /kr16_2_gazebo/joint3_position_controller/state
> /kr16_2_gazebo/joint4_position_controller/command
> /kr16_2_gazebo/joint4_position_controller/pid/parameter_descriptions
> /kr16_2_gazebo/joint4_position_controller/pid/parameter_updates
> /kr16_2_gazebo/joint4_position_controller/state
> /kr16_2_gazebo/joint5_position_controller/command
> /kr16_2_gazebo/joint5_position_controller/pid/parameter_descriptions
> /kr16_2_gazebo/joint5_position_controller/pid/parameter_updates
> /kr16_2_gazebo/joint5_position_controller/state
> /kr16_2_gazebo/joint6_position_controller/command
> /kr16_2_gazebo/joint6_position_controller/pid/parameter_descriptions
> /kr16_2_gazebo/joint6_position_controller/pid/parameter_updates
> /kr16_2_gazebo/joint6_position_controller/state
> /kr16_2_gazebo/joint_states
> /rosout
> /rosout_agg
> ```

and robot is just like hanging on base link, because base link is only one which has type=fixed and all other have type=revolute.

here is picture of hanging robot:

[image]

When I lift and release robot in gazebo using mouse, robot just fall down and axis are just shaking like there is no motor or any force which keeps them fixed.

Comment: It probably happens due to a difference in orientation of the World axes and the URDF axes. Can you share the URDF?

Comment: Did you solve this problem？I have the same problem。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason why robot is laying down is because in urdf file gravity is not turned off. When I add this part of the code to my urdf then robot is loaded in some position and is not falling down.

```
  <!-- Gazebo-specific link properties  -->
  <gazebo reference="${prefix}base_link">
    <material>Gazebo/Yellow</material>
    <turnGravityOff>true</turnGravityOff>
  </gazebo>
  <gazebo reference="${prefix}link_1">
    <material>Gazebo/Orange</material>
    <turnGravityOff>true</turnGravityOff>
  </gazebo>
  <gazebo reference="${prefix}link_2">
    <material>Gazebo/Orange</material>
    <turnGravityOff>true</turnGravityOff>
  </gazebo>  
  <gazebo reference="${prefix}link_3">
    <material>Gazebo/Orange</material>
    <turnGravityOff>true</turnGravityOff>
  </gazebo>
  <gazebo reference="${prefix}link_4">
    <material>Gazebo/Orange</material>
    <turnGravityOff>true</turnGravityOff>
  </gazebo>
  <gazebo reference="${prefix}link_5">
    <material>Gazebo/Orange</material>
    <turnGravityOff>true</turnGravityOff>
  </gazebo>
  <gazebo reference="${prefix}link_6">
    <material>Gazebo/Black</material>
    <turnGravityOff>true</turnGravityOff>
  </gazebo>
```

I am not sure that I want turned off gravity in simulation.

Answer (score 1):

A. It seems your robot is not fixed to gazebo world so you have to add a joint to fix in gazebo environment.
Add below content into your urdf file and child link should be your base link name.
[image]

B. Fine tune damping and friction values of dynamics tag for all joints in urdf file.

C. if more of your robot start vibrating than fine tune PID gain values from your either controller.yaml file or joint_parameter.yaml file.

Comment: Welcome to Robotics:SE.  As with other sites on Stack Exchange (and other tech sites in general), it's generally preferred if code snippets are included in questions and answers as properly formatted text, [rather than images](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Comment: will take care in future...thank you for suggestion

Answer (score 0):

look at this tutorial. You have to add some gazebo specific tag in URDF file.

http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_urdf

Answer (score 0):

This is happening for two reasons:

1. An "inertia" element within each "link" element must be properly specified and configured.
2. Maybe you don't have any proper controller for each joint. See http://wiki.ros.org/ros_control

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for late answer but I was little bit busy. Here is my urdf file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!-- =================================================================================== -->
<!-- |    This document was autogenerated by xacro from kr16_2.xacro                   | -->
<!-- |    EDITING THIS FILE BY HAND IS NOT RECOMMENDED                                 | -->
<!-- =================================================================================== -->
<!--Generates a urdf from the macro in kr16_2_macro.xacro -->
<robot name="kuka_kr16_2" xmlns:xacro="http://wiki.ros.org/xacro">
  <!-- LINKS -->
  <!-- base link -->
  <link name="base_link">
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <mass value="2"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.01" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.01" iyz="0" izz="0.01"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://kuka_kr16_support/meshes/kr16_2/visual/base_link.dae"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://kuka_kr16_support/meshes/kr16_2/collision/base_link.stl"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <!-- link 1 (A1) -->
  <link name="link_1">
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <mass value="2"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.01" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.01" iyz="0" izz="0.01"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://kuka_kr16_support/meshes/kr16_2/visual/link_1.dae"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://kuka_kr16_support/meshes/kr16_2/collision/link_1.stl"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <!-- link 2 -->
  <link name="link_2">
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <mass value="2"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.01" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.01" iyz="0" izz="0.01"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://kuka_kr16_support/meshes/kr16_2/visual/link_2.dae"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://kuka_kr16_support/meshes/kr16_2/collision/link_2.stl"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <!-- link 3 -->
  <link name="link_3">
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <mass value="2"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.01" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.01" iyz="0" izz="0.01"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://kuka_kr16_support/meshes/kr16_2/visual/link_3.dae"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://kuka_kr16_support/meshes/kr16_2/collision/link_3.stl"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <!-- link 4 -->
  <link name="link_4">
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <mass value="2"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.01" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.01" iyz="0" izz="0.01"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://kuka_kr16_support/meshes/kr16_2/visual/link_4.dae"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://kuka_kr16_support/meshes/kr16_2/collision/link_4.stl"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <!-- link 5 -->
  <link name="link_5">
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <mass value="2"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.01" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.01" iyz="0" izz="0.01"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://kuka_kr16_support/meshes/kr16_2/visual/link_5.dae"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://kuka_kr16_support/meshes/kr16_2/collision/link_5.stl"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <!-- link 6 -->
  <link name="link_6">
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <mass value="2"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.01" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.01" iyz="0" izz="0.01"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://kuka_kr16_support/meshes/kr16_2/visual/link_6.dae"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://kuka_kr16_support/meshes/kr16_2/collision/link_6.stl"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <!-- tool 0 -->
  <!-- This frame corresponds to the $FLANGE coordinate system in KUKA KRC controllers. -->
  <link name="tool0"/>
  <!-- END LINKS -->
  <!-- JOINTS -->
  <!-- joint 1 (A1) -->
  <joint name="joint_a1" type="revolute">
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.675"/>
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="link_1"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 -1"/>
    <limit effort="0" lower="-3.22885911619" upper="3.22885911619" velocity="2.72271363311"/>
  </joint>
  <!-- joint 2 (A2) -->
  <joint name="joint_a2" type="revolute">
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.26 0 0"/>
    <parent link="link_1"/>
    <child link="link_2"/>
    <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
    <limit effort="0" lower="-2.70526034059" upper="0.610865238198" velocity="2.72271363311"/>
  </joint>
  <!-- joint 3 (A3) -->
  <joint name="joint_a3" type="revolute">
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.68 0 0"/>
    <parent link="link_2"/>
    <child link="link_3"/>
    <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
    <limit effort="0" lower="-2.26892802759" upper="2.68780704807" velocity="2.72271363311"/>
  </joint>
  <!-- joint 4 (A4) -->
  <joint name="joint_a4" type="revolute">
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.67 0 -0.035"/>
    <parent link="link_3"/>
    <child link="link_4"/>
    <axis xyz="-1 0 0"/>
    <limit effort="0" lower="-6.10865238198" upper="6.10865238198" velocity="5.75958653158"/>
  </joint>
  <!-- joint 5 (A5) -->
  <joint name="joint_a5" type="revolute">
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <parent link="link_4"/>
    <child link="link_5"/>
    <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
    <limit effort="0" lower="-2.26892802759" upper="2.26892802759" velocity="5.75958653158"/>
  </joint>
  <!-- joint 6 (A6) -->
  <joint name="joint_a6" type="revolute">
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <parent link="link_5"/>
    <child link="link_6"/>
    <axis xyz="-1 0 0"/>
    <limit effort="0" lower="-6.10865238198" upper="6.10865238198" velocity="10.7337748998"/>
  </joint>
  <!-- tool frame - fixed frame -->
  <joint name="joint_a6-tool0" type="fixed">
    <parent link="link_6"/>
    <child link="tool0"/>
    <origin rpy="0 1.57079632679 0" xyz="0.158 0 0"/>
  </joint>
  <!-- END JOINTS -->
  <!-- ROS base_link to KUKA $ROBROOT coordinate system transform -->
  <link name="base"/>
  <joint name="base_link-base" type="fixed">
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="base"/>
  </joint>
</robot>
```